# Как через приложение открывать папки в которые нет доступа?

Tags: ubuntu

Какими способами можно открыть папку в программе?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В какой именно программе? в Nautilus? Как вариант, запустить Nautilus из-под root'а, выставить права/владельца на нужные файлы/каталоги, и потом открывать штатным способом. Либо если один раз нужно, то открыть один раз из-под root'а и сделать всё что нужно.

Comment: Приложение через sudo не запускается. gitKraken. Он не видит ssh agent почему то.

Comment: `$ sudo chown -R manking:manking /home/manking` (и перестаньте, пожалуйста, запускать всё подряд от имени пользователя root).

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, *открыть один раз из-под root'а и сделать всё что нужно* — всё-таки не стоит давать «чайникам» явно вредные советы. вот автор вопроса уже им последовал. в результате чего уже не имеет доступа к части своего домашнего каталога.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ну если у человека софтина, запущенная от имени %username%, не видит подкаталог, лежащий в /home/%username%, значит, у него УЖЕ что-то идёт не так. это первое. второе - чем может повредить рекурсивная раздача прав самому себе на свой собственный хомяк? пусть и через рута

Comment: @alexanderbarakin а сами-то?)) кто ему судо посоветовал?) это же и есть то же самое что и я написал по сути

Comment: @КапитанФлинт, *это же и есть то же самое что и я написал по сути* — нет. я посоветовал воспользоваться правами root **именно для** выполнения административных действий. вы же дали вредную рекомендацию (аналогичной автор уже последовал, последствия — в тексте вопроса), **по сути** звучащую как «если чего-то там не сработало, попробуйте добавить sudo».

Comment: Вот создал тему
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/878090/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-root