# GitKraken не видит ssh агент по умолчанию

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, gitkraken

Когда делаю pull в репозитории, то выводится ошибка(ниже на скриншоте красным)
Я так понимаю что он или не видит его или нужно еще что то до настроить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как понять какие переменные окружения были установлены ssh агентом?

Comment: вот эти?
SSH_AGENT_PID 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK

А их можно задать глобально чтобы они всегда были доступны для всех программ?

Comment: Всё равно непонятно. Для npm install я могу прокидывать переменную окружения  так

sudo SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK npm install

А как её прокинуть в процесс когда запускаю программу через иконку?

Comment: Процесс работает от моего имени

Comment: совет я дал в [соседнем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/877618/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b0#comment1425762_877618). но если вы продолжите использовать программу *sudo* (*su*) не по прямому назначению — для выполнения административных задач, то время от времени придётся разгребать последствия.

Comment: Опять же непонятно как передать этой программе переменную окружения SSH_AUTH_SOCK. 
Я её запускаю через клик по иконке, процесс gitkraken запускается под моим пользователем manking. У папки .ssh владелец manking и права 755 как и у всех файлов вложенных в неё. 
Нужно что то еще сделать с ssh агентом или с настройками самой программы gitkraken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так и не понятно почему gitkraken не может открыть и посмотреть каталог .ssh 
даже если ему и всем файлам там ставить права 777.

Но можно в настройках программы сгенерировать новый ключ который будет лежать примерно так, либо положить готовый ключ туда.

```
/home/USER/snap/gitkraken/94/gitkraken_rsa.pub
```

И сам выставиться в настройках gitkraken.

Пока это единственное решение