# Как работать с правами пользователя root?

Tags: ubuntu

Как работать в системе с правами пользователя root?
Вместо того чтобы вызывать каждый раз sudo.
Интересует самый правильный путь.

То есть я должен работать пользователем user1 с правами root, а не самим root?

Comment: вы не можете работать под user1 с правами root, нужны полные права становитесь root. `sudo -i` или `su - root` вам в помощь

Comment: Самый правильный путь `sudo -i`. Но из старых хакерских приемов есть такой: открываете файл `/etc/passwd`, находите там своего юзера `user1` и меняете ему `uid` и `gid` на 0. Перелогониваетесь этим юзером. profit!

Comment: самый правильный путь — **не** работать в системе с правами пользователя root. а использовать эти права **лишь** для администрирования системы.

Comment: А можно узнать зачем? Неужели "это ж мой комп, я тут хозяин и я хочу полный контроль"?

Comment: Ну например я выполняю 
некий скрипт npm install 

А дальше мне выводятся ошибки что недостаточно прав на создание каталога или записи в файл где либо.